# How can I determine why Firefox is burning CPU "Recalculating Style" when app idle?

Tags: javascript, css, performance, firefox

I have a situation where the CPU used by firefox jumps up to about 50% and does not decrease when I go to my app's tab. The app is idle, I am not clicking on anything, and no requests are being made. Yet the CPU does not drop.

I used Firebug to profile what was going on, but it returned that there was no javascript calls.

So then I used the most recent Performance profiler in Firefox 40. Running the profiler for about 5 seconds then stopping showed that the gecko engine was sending lots of calls to "Recalculate Style", specifically the hint given was that it is related to CSS Animations. See screenshot:

[image]

I need to find out what is causing this because I believe it is inherently slowing my app down. However, I am not sure what to do next in order to track down the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using CSS animations by any chance? You can turn on paint rectangles to see if the browser is redrawing something a lot.

Comment: Does it still happen with _JavaScript disabled?_ Look through your stylesheets for words like `animation`, `@keyframes`

Comment: Thanks guys. So on chrome I don't see any paint rectangles when sitting idle and my fps meter is hovering around 57. So I believe this is good. However, that doesn't help me diagnose why it is behaving so poorly in Firefox. Unfortunatly I cannot run the app without javascript and the codebase is quite large, so a code review is not going to be very effective. Any suggestions on what I could try inside firefox to pinpoint the issue?

Comment: One thing to note, is that when I look at the call tree in firefox, none of my javascript is referenced, it is all just browser related stuff.

Comment: Here's a list of things that cause a reflow in the layout. http://readme.kinja.com/what-forces-layout-reflow-https-gist-github-com-paul-1734269216  If you are absolutely sure that your code is not being referenced, could there be a chance of a javascript extension that is running?  hope this helps!

Comment: Ah I figured it out, thank you @paul-s. After I did a code review based on keyframe I found some code that was animating an object out of view. Removed that and everything looks good now. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Problem turned out to be an animation that was off screen but Firefox was still burning CPU calculating the keyframes etc.